# Timeout/expire a Mac file sharing connection

Tags: macos, mac, windows, smb, file-sharing

I've set up file sharing from my Mac so I can connect to it from my Windows machine. I used to have to enter my password on the Windows every once in a while (few hours), but lately the credentials seem to stay around and I don't need to enter my password.

I want to restore things to the way they were so the credentials are expired after a couple of hours. I'm assuming this can be done on the Mac and maybe on the Windows but I couldn't find how to do it.